# Sparql query pattern matching with filter result

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, dbpedia

I'm new to running sparql queries and I'm not very experienced. I've developed a java application that executes queries that comply with a given pattern provided by the user.
For example, I synthesize the pattern to make the query in this simplified way: "P (? X,? Y), Q (? X,? Z), Q (? Y,? Z)"
where P and Q are properties that bind two individuals in the first case "?x" and "?y", in the second "?x" and "?z" and in the third "?y" and "?z". For example, a possible answer to the metaquery is the following "isMarriedTo (?x,?y), livesIn (?x,?y), livesIn (?y,?z)"
I have tried the metaquery on YAGO but also on DBPEDIA, but the results are not what they want.
Here is the query I made:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?x ?y ?z ?p ?q
WHERE{
GRAPH <http://dbpedia.org> {

     ?x ?p ?y.
     ?x ?q ?z.

  filter ( ?p != ?q )
  filter ( ?x != ?y )
  filter ( ?x != ?z )
  filter ( ?y != ?z )
  }
}LIMIT 20
```

My intent is to select from this query all instances that respect this pattern P (? X,? Y) and simultaneously Q (? X,? Z).
I get some unsuccessful results for my purpose, for example I would like to avoid ontology results such as "...rdf-schema#label" I would be interested in "real" results concrete in short.
Here is the result url given the query above.

[Results with previous query](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fx%20%3Fy%20%3Fz%20%3Fp%20%3Fq%0D%0AWHERE%7B%0D%0AGRAPH%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Fx%20%3Fp%20%3Fy.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Fx%20%3Fq%20%3Fz.%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20filter%20%28%20%3Fp%20%21%3D%20%3Fq%20%29%0D%0A%20%20filter%20%28%20%3Fx%20%21%3D%20%3Fy%20%29%0D%0A%20%20filter%20%28%20%3Fx%20%21%3D%20%3Fz%20%29%0D%0A%20%20filter%20%28%20%3Fy%20%21%3D%20%3Fz%20%29%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7DLIMIT%2020&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20)

I would like the resulting tuples to be concrete including properties like "hasGivenName", "hasNeighbor", "wasBornOnDate" like this one.
For example, these are contained in this file [Yago scheme that include the properties that i'm interested to find binding](http://resources.mpi-inf.mpg.de/yago-naga/yago3.1/yagoSchema.txt)

Comment: And why don't you filter the properties then? Either based on the URI, e.g. `FILTER(STRSTARTS(STR(?p), "http://dbpedia.org/ontology/"))` or based on the type of the properties, e.g. `?p a ?p_type . VALUES ?p_type {owl:ObjectProperty owl:DatatypeProperty}` or ... and so on and so forth. You have to define how to restrict the possible properties.

Comment: By the way, you should always look for related work in research - looks like you're working on pattern detection, rule detection or something like that

Comment: Meanwhile, thank you very much, unfortunately I'm having several issues because I just started studying the queries, I wanted to ask if maybe limiting the results to a not very high number and sorting them randomly I might be able to get what I'm looking for? Because I can not understand how to get concrete results by running a generic query. Because in my developed application I use the JENA library I might eventually receive the results and then filter them from the application itself. Do you have a hand on how to make a generic query?

Comment: Maybe I found a way to do it, I'd like to work on the .ttl (yago turtle) file available at [YagoSchema](http://resources.mpi-inf.mpg.de/yago-naga/yago3.1/yagoSchema.ttl.7z)  can I query with Jena on this .ttl file and extrapolate the information I need? thank you very much

Comment: The YAGO schema doesn't contain instance data ... so how do you want to determine the properties used in your "meta-query"?

Comment: In general, I don't understand your problem now. What is the problem with running the query above  + my filter suggestion on the triple store that contains the instance data? Does something not work? By the way, usually, it's better to setup a local triple store and load the data. The public endpoint is not really aimed for complex and expensive queries as it's supposed to be a shared service.

Comment: @AKSW I tried to filter the query with those tips, it works but with non-generic queries but actually takes too long to return the results, plus if I quit the query in this way [Query](https://codepaste.net/achs55), get some concrete results for the values of ?x, ?y but the variable ?z and ?q which should also be a property contains values that are not useful for my purpose, applying the same reasoning for the ?q variable (?q a ?q_type. VALUES? q_type {owl: ObjectProperty owl: DatatypeProperty}) does not return any result . How could I do?

Comment: Restricting the search space of possible solutions is up to you. I showed that one option would be to FILTER on the namespace of the URI. Another option that I showed you was to use additional triple patterns that restrict the possible resources matching a variable. Your link doesn't work for me. Without seeing current query and without specifying what exactly should (not) occur it's impossible to give more hints.

Comment: And of course, the query is expensive. The selectivity of the triple patterns is low, thus, intermediate resultsets are big, thus, etc..

Comment: By the way, I strongly suggest **not** to use the public DBpedia endpoint for this. It has limited resources shared among all users. And indeed it has a timeout for queries.

Comment: @AKSW I downloaded JENA FUSEKI to run local queries,I started the server and uploaded Dbpedia ontology,but the query does not show any results. How could I do?[Query1] (https://ibb.co/iiYsQm) [Query2] (https://ibb.co/e6C8y6) [Query3] (https://ibb.co/b8Zoy6) For my purpose, just run the query whose triples are concrete and do not contain triples that have no meaning (for example"rdfs: subClassOf", "rdfs: label" "rdf-syntax-ns # type" etc.) To make you understand, I would like to understand threefold for the human being of the kind: "Dante wrote the Divine Comedy" and other results of this kind.

Comment: Which DBpedia data did you load exactly? Just the DBpedia ontology is not enough - this only contains the schema but **not** the instance data. For your task, you need the instance data

Comment: @AKSW I've now added triple proofs by downloading the .ttl (GEO COORDINATES) file from here [DBpediaDATASET](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/downloads-2016-10) , but the query does not show any results yet. why? Queries are the same as in the previous screenshots.

Comment: There is no other solution. If you want to work on the instance data, and this data doesn't fit into memory,  then you have to load the instance data into a database, i.e. a triple store. Querying is then done on your local triple store

Comment: No no no, what do you want with the Geo coordinates? This contains triples like `<http://wikidata.dbpedia.org/resource/Q100000> <http://www.georss.org/georss/point> "50.833333333333336 5.766666666666667" <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadier_en_Keer?oldid=725881850> .`

Comment: You need something like http://downloads.dbpedia.org/2016-10/core-i18n/en/mappingbased_objects_en.ttl.bz2 and http://downloads.dbpedia.org/2016-10/core-i18n/en/specific_mappingbased_properties_en.ttl.bz2

Comment: @AKSW Thank you now works, but I noticed that if I add "ORDER BY RAND()"to get random results since I'm interested in a tight set of results as much as possible, it puts me much more time, can you do something?
Then I wanted to check if the solution really coincided with the pattern I defined by the query. For example, consider the first record of this screenshot [QUERY](https://ibb.co/bV3kT6) I have drawn this small "graph" that should mirror the query, according to you is correct? Are the links right or are there any conceptual errors? [Graph](https://ibb.co/mda4MR) thank you very much

Comment: You're asking me whether this makes sense? Why not, a music album usually has a record label which produced the album. And indeed an album has some artist which itself sometimes has a contract with a record label.

Comment: `ORDER BY` is always expensive and depending on the implementation does a full scan of the resultset

Comment: @AKSW With the graph I designed I meant if the results of the query actually represent the constraints that I was looking for in the query. Because if so, I could apply this solution to any generic query of that type (such as what I did as an example)

Comment: The results match the query. What else should they do? And your query represents a rule `p(x,y), q(y,z) -> q(x,z)` - whether this makes sense or not doesn't matter for the SPARQL query engine.

Comment: @AKSW I thank you very much, you have been very kind, now I wanted to ask you, can you make this query with jena fuseki with eclipse? Because I need to integrate with software I'm making.